Why don’t I see network requests in Chrome DevTools Performance tab like in older versions?
I've been following a web performance tutorial from about 4 years ago, and the instructor's Chrome DevTools Performance tab shows network requests (CSS, JS, etc.) directly in the timeline, alongside CPU, rendering, and JavaScript execution tasks.
However, in my current version of Chrome (Version 129.0.6668.59 - I don't know if it's relevant in this case), I don't see the network requests in the Performance tab, despite looking through the settings.

I checked the Performance tab settings (via the settings icon under the performance tab) but couldn't find any option to enable network tracking in the timeline.

I can capture network activity in the Network tab separately, but it doesn’t appear in the Performance tab like it does in the tutorial.


I’ve included a screenshot from the tutorial (older version of Chrome DevTools) and a screenshot from my current setup for comparison:

Tutorial screenshot
My screenshot

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is not a code related issue
